# Made own service like cron in mac os how to run this scheduler service in a plist on mac os

Tags: ios, linux, macos

Made own service  like cron in mac os  how to run this scheduler service in a plist on mac os .how this service scheduler service will run through launchd.

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: i have seen this link.

Comment: but exactly whats happening when i load plist of my service .It will start first time and parent is launchd .but when i unload the plist its not unloading still pid for this service is there.

Comment: so i kill it from kill -9 .After this service is not starting when i tried to load plist of my service. Please any one tell why it is happening.

Comment: Well I would expect an "unload" to stop the service, so it's possibly a bug in your code (for example ignoring signals).  However that's all I can tell you with limited information in your question. I would recommend adding logging to your service in order to see what's happening.

Comment: when i try to load service .In /var/log/system.log giving this error .  com.apple.launchd[1] (com.sched): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
Jul  9 13:59:14 --- last message repeated 2 times ---

Comment: would u tell me one more question if i have 3rd party code can i run this in mac as in linux?

Comment: Sounds like more bugs in your code.  As I have said in my previous comment, add logging to get some insight as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

To run a scheduled task through Launchd on macOS, you need to:

1. Create a task definition file (.plist)
2. Put the file into `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
3. Use `Launchctl` to manage the task

If you want to run a task at 14:30 everyday, you need to add `StartCalendarInterval` into the task definition file (.plist) :

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>14</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
```

If you don't know how to write a plist file, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html) is a good start.

Here are useful commands about Launchctl:

```
# Load task
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myname.launch.some.program.plist

# Remove task
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myname.launch.some.program.plist

# Manually execute task
launchctl start com.myname.launch.some.program

# List all tasks
launchctl list
```

To get more detailed information and instructions, you can also read [this](https://zeckli.github.io/en/2016/01/05/use-launchd-on-mac-en.html).